# Equivalent command in webdriver for a css selector command

Tags: python, webdriver

In firebug , when I run in console the below css selector , I get some output nodes like this...Eventually i can extract info from these nodes...

```
$$("div.skuCol>div.priceBox>div.bFont")
```

Result :

```
[div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont,
div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont,
div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont,
div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont,
div.bFont, div.bFont, div.bFont]
```

How can I run the above command in webdriver ...Current i do this in python like this ....

```
    from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
    from lxml import etree
    import requests
    from StringIO import StringIO

    #Sorting by low to high
    r = requests.get("http://%s.somewebsite.com/ps/?q=mango&o=pricelth&p=1")
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(r.content), parser)
    #Note this line...
    sel = CSSSelector("div.skuCol:not([style^='display']) > div.priceBox > div.bFont")
    nodes = sel(tree.getroot())
    s_list = []
    for node in nodes:
        s_list.append(float(node.text.split(" ")[-1]))

    print s_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
elements =  driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.skuCol>div.priceBox>div.bFont)
#iterate the array and do something with the elements after this
```

Comment: More correctly, `find_elements_by_css_selector(...)`, since he wants to get them all, not just the first one.  But otherwise, +1.